# Slick 3.0 Error When Selecting from H2 Database

Tags: h2, slick

When I use a H2 database for my application, I get the following error message. The select statement seems a bit problematic:

```
select "powerPlantId", "orgName", "isActive", "minPower", "maxPower", "rampRate", "rampRateSecs", "powerPlantType", "createdAt", "updatedAt" from "powerPlant" where "isActive" = true
```

I get the following message:

```
select "powerPlantId", "orgName", "isActive", "minPower", "maxPower", "rampRate", "rampRateSecs", "powerPlantType", "createdAt", "updatedAt" from "powerPlant" where "isActive" = true;
Table "powerPlant" not found; SQL statement:
select "powerPlantId", "orgName", "isActive", "minPower", "maxPower", "rampRate", "rampRateSecs", "powerPlantType", "createdAt", "updatedAt" from "powerPlant" where "isActive" = true [42102-196] 42S02/42102 (Help)
```

I guess the double quotes are messing it up! Any ideas why Slick does this to the generated SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`

So the following connection string sort of got rid of the error:

```
db.url = "jdbc:h2:~/path/to/db/file;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;IFEXISTS=TRUE"
```

The key was to have this parameter which got rid of the error!

```
DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
```

###### Further Reading:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ah2database.com+%22database_to_upper%22